# How to print parameters in downstream job by upstream job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm new into Jenkins pipeline. I want to pass parameters from Upstream Job to Downstream job. But I'm not getting any way to print those parameters. And I don't want to use any plugin. Please help. Thanks. 
Here is my code for Upstream job:

```
echo "Hey There!!"
build job : 'DownStream-Job',
    parameters: [
            string(name: 'param1', value: "HI"),
            string(name: 'param2', value: "BYE")
    ]
```

I want to print *param1* and *param2* in downstream job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters are available in jobs in the `params` object.

```
// DownStream-Job.groovy
// declarative
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        string name: 'param1'
        string name: 'param2'
    }

    stages {
        stage('Print params') {
            steps {
                echo params.param1
                echo params.param2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
// DownStream-Job.groovy
// scripted
node() {
    echo params.param1
    echo params.param2
}
```